# What is the risk of hardcoded credentials in creating database connection?

Tags: security, credentials

Hi security aware people,

I have recently scanned my application with a tool for static code analysis and one of the high severity findings is a hardcoded username and password for creating a connection:

```
dm.getConnection(databaseUrl,"server","revres");
```

Why does the scanner think this is a risk for the application? I can see some downsides such as not being able to change the password easily if it's compromised. Theoretically someone could reverse-engineer the binaries to learn the credentials. But I don't see the advantage of storing the credentials in a config file, where they are easy to locate and read, unless they are encrypted. And if I encrypt them, I will be solving the same problem with the encryption key...

Are there any more risks that I cannot see? Or should I use a completely different approach?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed password embedded in the code will be the same for every installation, and accessible by anyone with access to the source code or binary (including the installation media).

A password read from a file can be different for each installation, and known only to those who can read the password file.

Typically, your installer will generate a unique password per site, and write that securely to the file to be read by your application.  (By "securely", I mean using `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` to prevent symlink attacks, and with a correct selection of file location and permissions before anyone else can open it).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one, I can give you examples for a .Net application (as you haven't specified running environment / technologies used). Although my guess is Java? I hope this is still relevant and helps you.

My main advice would be to read this article and go from there: [Protecting Connection information - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a page that describes [working with encrypted configuration files here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)

I've seen this solved both using encrypted configuration files and windows authentication. I think that running your application as a user that will be granted access to the relevant stored procedures etc (as little as possible, e.g. Principle of Least Privilege) and furthermore folder access etc is a good route.

I would recommend using both techniques because then you can give relevant local folder access to the pool for IIS and split out your user access in SQL etc. This also makes for better auditing!

This depends on your application needs though. The main reason to make this configurable via a config file or environmental user account I would say is so that when you come to publish your application to production, your developers do not need access to the production user account information and instead can just work with Local / System test / UAT credentials instead.

And of course they are not stored in plain text in your source control checkin then either, which if you host in a private distributed network like GIT could mean that this could be compromised and a hacker would gain access to the credentials.

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on how accessible / secure your source code or compiled code is. Developers usually have copies of the code on their dev boxes, which are usually not nearly as secure as production servers, and so are much more easily hacked. Generally, a test user / pw is configured on the dev box, and in production, the "real" pw is stored in much more secure config files. Yes, if someone hacked into the server they could easily get the credentials, but that is much more difficult than getting into a dev box in most cases. But like I said it depends. If there is only one dev, and they have a super secure machine they work with, and the repo for their code is also super secure, then there is no effective difference.

Comment: That is pretty much what I was thinking, but I wanted to make sure. This is a small application that only I am responsible for, so the risk is not so high in my opinion. Of course, the static code analysis tool cannot take into account factors such as the size of dev team or the level of security of different environments (I use DEV,UAT,PROD), so the severity classification is probably based on the assumption it is a large enterprise application.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is to ask the credentials to end user initially and then encrypt and store them in a file. This way, I don't know their connection details and passwords as a dev. The key is a hashed binary and I store it by poking ekstra bytes in between. One who wants to crack it should find out the algorithm used, key and vector lengths, their location and the start-end positions of the byte sequence keeping the values. A genius, who would also reverse engineer my code to get all this information would break into it (but it might be easier to directly crack the end user's credentials).

Comment: I would ask to the downvoter the reason. SO shouldn't allow downvoting without a reason. It is like execution without defence and generally those who doesn't understand what is meant do that just because they can.